# Exim ACL to drop if friendly name in From header matches substring

Tags: exim

I'm getting a particularly horrible type of spam that's easily identified by a plain text name in the From header.

Basically the format is like this:

```
From: "foo" <some-random-address@example.com>
```

I'd like to write an ACL data condition that checks if `foo` is in the From header. How would you do this?

I believe it would go in the [DATA ACL](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-access_control_lists.html#SECID193) part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think Jim U's answer might be a better way to achieve my goals, but for the record, here's how I did it within the DATA ACL:

```
acl_check_data:
  # Blacklist if friendly name matches any patterns.
  drop
    condition = ${if match{$h_from:}{"foo"}}
    message = Blacklisted.
    log_message = Blacklisted nasty.
```

This results in a `550 Blacklisted.` error to the SMTP client and immediately closes the connection.

Comment: This is a better solution IMHO because the spammer will see that the message has been rejected, rather than thinking it was sent successfully.  Note that the second `match` parameter is actually a regex, so in my case I wanted to block any e-mails that had my own domain in the from header's text part, so I used `match{$h_from:}{\@example\.com}`

Answer (score 3):

Conditionally discards mail based on header fields:

**exim.conf**

```
system_filter = /etc/exim/system_filter.conf
```

**system_filter.conf**

```
if $header_from matches "foo.*<"
or $header_from contains "@morespam.com"
or $h_subject contains "Viagra"
then
  seen finish
endif
```

---

The first condition will only match if foo appears in the friendly portion of the From header. The regex is case-insensitive.

It's best to test the filter file after you make any changes. Syntax errors in `system_filter.conf` will make incoming messages temporarily undeliverable.

**Test**

```
exim -bF /etc/exim/system_filter.conf <spam.eml
```

**spam.eml**

```
Subject: This is Spam Viagra
From: Fred Foo Jones <someuser@example.com>
To: John Smith <someother@mydomain.com>
Date: Mon, 22 Aug 2016 07:26:20 -0500

This is the body of the e-mail.
```

The test will tell you if the message would be delivered, discarded ("Seen finish"), or if there errors in the filter file (you get a message like, `Filter error: unknown filtering command "asldkf" near line 75 of filter file`)

---

Not an ACL solution, but it's easy for me to maintain. I only need to update system_filter.conf` when conditions change.

I place `system_filter` at the top of the exim.conf file (Main Configuration Settings). `seen finish` is the *blackhole* command; it instructs exim that it's finished processing the message.

Reference: [Exim filter files](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/filter_ch-exim_filter_files.html)

Comment: Will this generate a 5xx SMTP error?